# Direct product of hopfian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

This is a question about Hirshon's paper "The center and the commutator subgroup in hopfian groups"(https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afm/1485894451). Theorem 12 stating that if $B$ is a perfect group with finitely many normal subgroups and $A$ is a hopfian group, then the direct product $A \times B$ is hopfian. Is it possible to weaken the "finitely many normal subgroups" hypothesis?

Comment: This is a weird question... are you asking whether every perfect group has finitely any normal subgroups? or whether Hirshon skipped a hypothesis (in which case you should elaborate)

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afm/1485894451

Comment: It's impossible to understand your question without looking at the paper; I just did. It's indeed not very clear what are the assumptions: the statement of the theorem is "*If $B$ is a perfect group then $A\times B$ is hopfian.*". The abstract summarizes the results. It seems that the only standing assumptions are that $A$ and $B$ are hopfian (and, in this precise theorem, that $B$ is perfect).

Comment: @Ycor Thanks for providing the link. I think $B$ doesn't have to be assumed to be hopfian. But the hidden hypothesis "finitely many normal subgroups" is needed in Hirshon's proof.

Comment: @ARG $B$ hopfian is clearly a necessary condition for $A\times B$ to be hopfian. (And obviously a group with finitely many normal subgroups is hopfian)

Comment: OK the paper indeed starts with "*Throughout the paper $A$ is a hopfian group and $B$ is (unless we specify otherwise) a group with finitely many normal subgroups*". Theorem 12 says "*If $B$ is a perfect group then $A\times B$ is hopfian.* It is not "specified otherwise". So indeed $B$ is assumed to have finitely many normal subgroups. (This answer the question before it was edited.)

Comment: Certainly this "finitely many normal subgroups" is an overkill and should be weakened. The most optimistic statement would be that $A,B$ hopfian implies $A\times B$ hopfian (this would be an if-and-only-if). Unfortunately it's not mentioned, and I can't find any reference in Hirshon's survey "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086902800135?via%3Dihub" (where he addresses as open problem whether hopfian is stable under taking direct product with $\mathbf{Z}$)

Comment: @YCor A.L.S. Corner, in "Three examples of hopficity in torsion-free abelian groups" (Acta Mathematica Academiae Scientiarum Hungarica 16, pp.303-310, 1965) gives examples of two hopfian groups whose direct product is non-hopfian, and even of a hopfian group $A$ with $A\times A$ non-hopfian.

Comment: @JeremyRickard thank you! Corner's article is not cited in Hirshon's 1971 paper given by the OP, but it's indeed cited in Hirshon's 2002 survey (cited p4 - number 368) "*Misbehaved direct products*" mentioned in my previous comment. By the way the constructed hopfian $A$ with non-hopfian $A^2$ is abelian.

Comment: Right. I think the best result Hirshon got is $A$ is strong hopfian and $B$ has finitely many normal subgroups.